# Xcode: "Hide Navigator" ⌘, 0 stopped working. Why did it disappear?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

In Xcode, there is a keyboard shortcut to hide the navigator, ⌘,0. But it stopped working. I went to system preferences and manually added it back but it disappeared again. Why does this keep happening?

Comment: The shortcut works for me. You could submit feedback to Apple if you think it's a bug using [Feedback Assistant](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that I had the developer documentation window open. For some reason, when this window is open, the "Hide Navigator" keyboard shortcut is no longer active. For all currently open Xcode windows. However, the command (⌘, 0) works only once to close the navigator in the developer documentation window then stops working until you close the window.